# Hazelcast scheduling Cron jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, hazelcast, spring-scheduled

Can anybody help me with scheduling cron jobs with a help of Hazelcast? I know that Hazelcast has `IScheduledExecutorService`, but I can't find a way to schedule cron task (only delayed or interval jobs).

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast doesn't have that kind of functionality. You need to use a 3rd party system like quartz scheduler.